# How can I setup an X Server to run in the background on Windows?

Tags: ssh, terminal, cygwin, xorg

I have grown tired of the (visual) problems I get when using the combination of not-so-great terminal emulation+CygWin on Windows. Now I just run a forwarded gnome-terminal from my server when working in the terminal. The setup is quite simply using the Xserver I get through cygwin, which I start from the command line by issuing ´startx -- -multiwindows -clipboard´. The parameters means each program gets its own window. On a local network the performance is good enough for my needs.

**I have three problems with my current setup**

1. I need to manually issue startx from a console. I wish it could just start up in the background when I log in.
2. It seems startx, or rather the ~/.xinitrc needs to issue ´exec some-program´. Currently some xterm is started, which I have no use of. I would like this program to be non-visible.
3. I need to start up a console (or use the xterm window that xinit starts for me) and then manually issue ´ssh -Y myuser@myserver gnome-terminal´ to get things going. If I issue the command from another cygwin console then I also have to manually set ´DISPLAY´ to whatever it is at the moment.

**How can I automate/improve this setup?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are my findings so far: I have *got everything working except #3.*

1. Found out that the shortcut in the start menu did what I wanted. It starts up an Xserver on `DISPLAY=:0` by running
   `C:\cygwin\bin\run.exe /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -c /usr/bin/startxwin.exe` and uses multiwindows as the default. So simply by copying this shortcut (or creating my own with the same content) to the "Startup" folder in the start menu the X server is started on login.
2. I read the man file on startxwin. It seems that it will start xterm if it cannot find a `~/.startxwinrc` file. Simply by creating an empty file with this name I get what I want: nothing started and the X server is running.
3. Not quite there. I created a shortcut that runs the following command 
   `bash.exe -l -c  "DISPLAY=:0 ssh -Y myuser@myserver gnome-terminal"`. This creates a console window that logs into my server and then starts up the gnome-terminal. This is almost there, except for the "dummy" console. I tried prepending `"C:\cygwin\bin\run.exe"` to the command, but it just silently executes without anything happening.

Comment: Wouldn't it need a command separator like: bash.exe -l -c "DISPLAY=:0; ssh -Y myuser@myserver gnome-terminal" ?

Comment: @caffeine no, it is not a command. you can prefix any command with environment variables like `FOO=foo BAR=bar echo $FOO $BAR` and they will only be available for that command. It means they will not affect the environment the command is started from.